# Is LINQ2XML Descendants working in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml

I'm working on **Windows Phone 8 C#/XAML .NET 4.5 Application**

I'm trying to **select element with a given name** from an XML i'm getting, but when i try using `Descendants` to select it, it returns empty collection/list/array of results.

It returns fine when no name is selected, but when i try to search with name, it returns empty.

I'm probably just dumb and making a stupid mistake. Do you see some/can you explain?

**EXAMPLES:**

*myXMLString:*

```
<root>
  <element>
    <thisOne xmlns="something">example</thisOne>
  <element>
  <others></others>
</root>
```

*code:*

```
XDocument xmlData = XDocument.Parse(myXMLString);
//is always null
var thisOne = xmlData.Root.Descendants("thisOne").FirstOrDefault();
//returns the flattened version of the tree in a list
var descendants = xmlData.Root.Descedants().ToList();
```

Comment: The fact that the element you're trying to select has `xmlns="something"` (and that this was remarkable enough to include it in your question) should have been a big flashing indicator that there was something out of the ordinary about it and that it wasn't simply that `Descendants()` fails silently on Windows Phone 8.

Comment: I know that and thats why I'm asking. If you read the whole question, in the end I'm stating that I'm probably doing something wrong :)

Comment: Yeah, it's true that you said that. :)  Sorry for being a bit snippy.

Comment: I should have probably selected less "attention seeking" title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently looking for the elements called `thisOne` which aren't in a namespace. You need to specify the `something` namespace... the `xmlns="something"` part is specifying the default namespace for this element and further descendants. Fortunately, LINQ to XML makes it really easy to use XML namespaces:

```
XNamespace ns = "something";
var thisOne = xmlData.Root.Descendants(ns + "thisOne").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. Is there a way to select this element without knowing the namespace beforehand (I'm getting an XML response from a badly written SOAP webservice that changes a lot and its WSDL is bad so i cannot add it as webservice in my project :) )?

Comment: @mishan Even if the SOAP webservice uses different _prefixes_ for its namespaces from one call to the next, it's unlikely that the namespace _URIs_ (the `something` portion in this example) would actually change. As long as the URIs are consistent, the approach above should work.

Comment: @mishan: I concur with what JLRishe said - but if you *really* wanted to only use the local name, you could use `xmlData.Root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.LocalName == "thisOne")`.  I would recommend using the namespace though.

Comment: I used the namespace in the end. Nice touch with the localname I knew about but forgot due to not using it :)